# Escaping a INSERT query in sqlite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, escaping

How would folloing query be escaped properly in SQLITE? I don't seem to be able to find a working way to escape the fiel path at the end.

```
insert into mytable values ('IMG_1862_a.jpg', 'True', 'True', 'I:\where i've been\stock laptop\IMG_1862_a.jpg')
```

i tried a lot including:

```
    insert into mytable values ('IMG_1862_a.jpg', 'True', 'True', 'I:\where i^'ve been\stock laptop\IMG_1862_a.jpg') ESCAPE '^'
```

Comment: There must be a way to use placeholders in VB.NET, then you won't have to worry about manually quoting things.

Comment: what do you mean? can you make an example lease? thanks!

Comment: I don't know any VB.NET but the usually you supply some SQL with placeholders (`insert into t values(?, ?, ?)`) and then bind native values to the `?`-placeholders using API functions and let the library you're using worry about formatting things for the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, quotes in strings are escaped by doubling them:

```sql
insert into mytable values(..., 'I:\where i''ve been\stock laptop\IMG_1862_a.jpg')
```

However, you should always use parameters to avoid formatting problems like this, or [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/):

```
Dim sql As String = 'INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(@file, @a, @b, @path)'
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
With cmd.Parameters
    .Add(New SqlParameter("@file", "IMG_1862_a.jpg"))
    .Add(New SqlParameter("@a", "True"))
    .Add(New SqlParameter("@b", "True"))
    .Add(New SqlParameter("@path", "I:\where i've been\stock laptop\IMG_1862_a.jpg"))
End With
```